# How can I set a CSS rule to change the selection of all elements, not just text?

Tags: html, css, selection, textselection

This CSS rule …

```
::selection
{
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
::-moz-selection
{
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

… produces this effect in Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, some parts of the selection is default blue. How can I make the entire selection grey?

Answer (score 2):

-moz- is the prefix for firefox

try -webkit- it's for chrome and safari

Comment: The CSS is correct: WebKit, Opera and IE 9+ supports `::selection`.

Answer (score 1):

it must be in another `<div>` or something like that. Check around to fine anywhere else that sets a background colour. Without more code not much more we can do.

Also find the different brower types of

```
-moz-selection
```

as that is just firefox.

Comment: The CSS is correct: WebKit, Opera and IE 9+ supports `::selection`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to prevent selection of all elements on a page... Hope it helps!

```
*{
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```